# How i can get all named ranges on my spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google spreadsheet. In Spreadsheet class is a method setNamedRange, which allows you to create a named Range of. I need to get all named ranges in a worksheet. In Spreadsheet class has no method of obtaining all named ranges. How can I get a list of all named ranges in the worksheet spreadsheet google?

Answer (score 1):

As you already noticed, the Google Apps Script doesn't have yet a method to list all the named ranges in a Google spreadsheet. Please, star the following issue:

[Issue 4245: Named Ranges maintenance tools](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4245)